# Heroku and Node.js application deployment error H10 (App crashed)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have a Node.js app working on my local computer, but when I send it to Heroku, it crashes. The error log gives an error `fs-extra` and H10 error and says:

```
2019-07-27T10:26:04.960769+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:45:9)
2019-07-27T10:26:04.960771+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-27T10:26:04.960774+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-27T10:26:04.960776+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-27T10:26:04.977073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-27T10:26:04.977532+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-27T10:26:04.978645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! photo_gallery@1.0.0 start: `node src/index.js`
2019-07-27T10:26:04.978819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-27T10:26:04.979094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-27T10:26:04.979279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the photo_gallery@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-27T10:26:04.979480+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-27T10:26:04.987401+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T10:26:04.987599+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-27T10:26:04.987740+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-27T10_26_04_980Z-debug.log
2019-07-27T10:26:05.073078+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-27T10:26:05.050705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-27T16:02:15.908996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-27T16:02:18.219026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-27T16:02:20.146271+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T16:02:20.146290+00:00 app[web.1]: > photo_gallery@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-27T16:02:20.146293+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/index.js
2019-07-27T16:02:20.146295+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T16:02:20.963437+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb+srv://pablofonseca:mongoDeveloper3294MD@cluster0-6auoq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
2019-07-27T16:02:20.963482+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136238+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136242+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136244+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136246+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136248+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136250+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136252+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136254+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136256+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136258+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routes/index.js:13:12)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136260+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136262+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136264+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136266+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136268+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136272+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136274+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:45:9)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136276+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136278+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.136280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-27T16:02:21.147675+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-27T16:02:21.148310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-27T16:02:21.149706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! photo_gallery@1.0.0 start: `node src/index.js`
2019-07-27T16:02:21.149893+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-27T16:02:21.150233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-27T16:02:21.150467+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the photo_gallery@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-27T16:02:21.150692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-27T16:02:21.156522+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T16:02:21.156731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-27T16:02:21.156803+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-27T16_02_21_152Z-debug.log
2019-07-27T16:02:21.228062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-27T16:02:21.207666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-27T21:54:23.980325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-27T21:54:26.162423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-07-27T21:54:28.335412+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-07-27T21:54:28.335428+00:00 app[web.1]: > photo_gallery@1.0.0 start /app
2019-07-27T21:54:28.335430+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/index.js
2019-07-27T21:54:28.335431+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T21:54:28.934757+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb+srv://pablofonseca:mongoDeveloper3294MD@cluster0-6auoq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
2019-07-27T21:54:28.934788+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069816+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069819+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069821+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069824+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069827+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069829+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069831+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069833+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069834+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routes/index.js:13:12)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069836+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069837+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069839+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069840+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069842+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069843+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069845+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069847+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.js:45:9)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069848+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069850+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.069851+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-27T21:54:29.078039+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-27T21:54:29.078417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-27T21:54:29.079496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! photo_gallery@1.0.0 start: `node src/index.js`
2019-07-27T21:54:29.079602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-27T21:54:29.079795+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-07-27T21:54:29.079911+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the photo_gallery@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-27T21:54:29.080018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-27T21:54:29.084860+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-27T21:54:29.085002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-27T21:54:29.085091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-27T21_54_29_081Z-debug.log
2019-07-27T21:54:29.152385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-27T21:54:29.134549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-07-28T01:26:30.759278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=crgrupodediseno.herokuapp.com request_id=d37398a6-a39e-4165-bb4f-407f45eb695b fwd="201.192.136.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-28T01:26:31.316040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=crgrupodediseno.herokuapp.com request_id=50cdca96-9a21-4382-997b-3b2f81f5564e fwd="201.192.136.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the record I am receiving using the "heroku logs --tail" command.
Has anyone had this before, and know what might be causing the problem? I cannot find a solution.

Actually I have `fs-extra` module installed in my computer, and the application is running correctly in local, but in Heroku is not working.

Here I attached the code of my index.js file so you have an idea of how I am doing the settings:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

const Photo = require('../modules/Photo');

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

const fs = require('fs-extra');

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const photos = await Photo.find(); //Nos trae todas las fotos almacenadas en MongoDB.
    console.log(photos);
    res.render('images', { photos });
});

router.get('/images/add', async(req, res) => {
    const photos = await Photo.find(); //Nos trae todas las fotos almacenadas en MongoDB.
    res.render('image_form', { photos });

});

router.post('/images/add', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); //Informacion de la imagen
    const { title, description } = req.body;
    console.log(req.file); //Imagen
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    console.log(result);
    const newPhoto = new Photo({
        title: title,
        description: description,
        imageURL: result.url,
        public_id: result.public_id
    });
    await newPhoto.save();
    await fs.unlink(req.file.path);
    res.redirect('/images/add');
});
router.get('/images/delete/:photo_id', async(req, res) => {
    const { photo_id } = req.params;
    const photo = await Photo.findByIdAndDelete(photo_id); //Eliminar la información de la base de datos.
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(photo.public_id); //Eliminar la información subida a Cloudinary. 
    console.log(result);
    res.redirect('/images/add');

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I have `fs-extra` module installed in my computer

This is irrelevant. How would a module installed on your computer have any effect on Heroku?

Your dependencies must all be defined in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.

1. Add `fs-extra` and any other dependencies to your `package.json`,
2. run `npm install` or `yarn`,
3. commit your updated `package.json` and lock file,
4. then deploy again.

Heroku will install the dependencies listed in those files as part of the build process.

This is probably going to be a problem too:

```
PORT = 4000
```

but since you haven't shared your `server.js` it's hard to say for sure. Heroku [populates the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers) and this is the port your server must bind to.

Comment: Hi Chris, I had actually realized that I had an error with the port configuration in 4000. So I have set up a series of environment variables so that I can interact with Heroku in the right way. What happens is that I still have the error, the application does not work yet and gives me a similar log.

Comment: The port hint was to help with your likely _next_ problem. The answer to your question is in the first part here: add `fs-extra` to your dependency file and redeploy.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will do exactly that right now. Check the code that I have uploaded on my index.js file.